# OpenSSH resetting connection when I try to SSH

Tags: windows, openssh, ssh-keys, public-key, authorized-keys

I'm trying to set up my local Windows 7 machine to receive SSH connections so I tried to follow [this guide](https://hostadvice.com/how-to/how-to-install-an-openssh-server-client-on-a-windows-2016-server/) on how to install OpenSSH into a Windows machine to server as an SSH server.

I was able to follow all the way to the end (I also copied my public key to the `authorized_keys` file to make sure) but whenever I try to SSH into it (server and client is the same machine) it says the connection is reset:

```bsh
$ ssh domain.com
Connection reset by ----::----:----:----:----%16 port 22
```

Not really sure what to make of it and how to fix it.

---

I looked at log files and I got `unable to generate token for user`, and  `unable to get security token for user`. Some searching around led me to https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/issues/1053 and I did the solution regarding `secpol.msc`. However after trying again I still get the same errors.